# emacs -nw and emacs have different background color

Tags: emacs

In my `.emacs`, I am using this theme:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/bin/emacs-theme")
(load-theme 'monokai t)
```

It works when I open emacs in a standalone window: `emacs afile.c`.

But when I open emacs like `emacs -nw`, the background is green. How can I fix the background to be the same color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text terminals usually do not support more than 8 background colours. You can wrap your settings into

```
(if window-system ...)
```

Comment: Please this in where? .emacs?

Comment: @michael: Yes. You can specify the colours for the text based mode in the `else` part of the `if`.